# jQuery replace english words with Chinese words

Tags: jquery

I want to replace some words on my website with Chinese words. I am using jQuery to `replace` the words. This is my script

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event,request, settings ) {
  $('.base-search').html().replace('Find Accommodation','酒店价目表');
});
```

But the output doesnt change and when I check my script on the browser, it looks like this

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event,request, settings ) {
  $('.base-search').html().replace('Find Accommodation','é…’åº—ä»·ç›®è¡¨');
});
```

Why is that? and How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a Unicode problem. I would check the encoding of the file in whatever OS you're using as your dev machine first. Then check encoding of the HTML page and make sure you have the right encoding, for example:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```

Comment: in your case it's more likely to be the first one